# awkward tabular

Tags: tables

I have a need to create some awkward tabulars as shown below.[image] 
So far, I managed to create them to a certain degree (not perfect) as shown below.[image] I sure would like some help here to produce a better result as the original shown above. My MWE is shown below and hope some of you can lend some hands. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
        y = a_{0} +
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c}
                $b_{1}$                                            &
                $+\dfrac{1}{}$                                     &
                ------                                             &
                ------                                             &
                ------                                             \\
                                                                   &
                $\phantom{+} a_{2}$                                &
                $+\dfrac{b_{3}}{a_{3}}$                            &
                $\dfrac{+\dfrac{1}{b_{4}}}{+\dfrac{b_{1}}{a_{4}}}$ &
                ------                                             \\
                \hline
                $a_{1}$                                            &
                $+\dfrac{b_{2}}{a_{2}}$                            &
                $\dfrac{+\dfrac{1}{a_{3}}}{+\dfrac{b_{3}}{a_{3}}}$ &
                $\dfrac{\dfrac{}{+\dfrac{b_{4}}{a_{4}}}}{\dfrac{}{+\dfrac{b_{4}}{a_{4}}}}$ &
                ------                                             \\
        \end{tabular}
        \\
        \intertext{and}
        \\
        x = b_{0}
        \left|+\cfrac{1}{a_{1}
                \left|+\dfrac{b_{2}}{a_{2}}
                        \left|\dfrac{+\dfrac{1}{a_{3}}}{+\dfrac{b_{3}}{a_{3}}}
                                \left|\dfrac{\dfrac{}{+\dfrac{b_{4}+}{a_{4}+}}}
                                        {\dfrac{+\dfrac{1}{a_{4}+}}{+\dfrac{b_{4}}{a_{4}}}}
                                \right.
                        \right.
                \right.}
        \right.
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `\multirow` for this.

In the first array I've put the first plus after the first vertical rule for consistency.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\myplus}{\multirow{2}{*}{$+$}}
\newcommand{\mymul}[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{$#1$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{array}{l*4{|l>{$}p{1.5em}<{$}}|p{1.5em}}
     &&\mymul{b_{1}}&\myplus& 1 &&&&& \\
     \cline{5-10}
     &&&&&&\mymul{b_{3}}&\myplus& 1 & \\
     \cline{9-10}
     &&&&\mymul{a_{2}}&\myplus&&& a_{4} & \\
     \cline{7-10}
     &&&&&&\mymul{a_{3}}&\myplus& b_{4} & \\
     \cline{9-10}
     \mymul{y_{0}=a_{0}}&\myplus&&&&&&& a_{4} & \\
     \cline{3-10}
     &&&&\mymul{b_{2}}&\myplus& 1 &&& \\
     \cline{7-10}
     &&&&&&\mymul{a_{3}}&\myplus& b_{4} & \\
     \cline{9-10}
     &&\mymul{a_{1}}&\myplus&&&&& a_{4} & \\
     \cline{5-10}
     &&&&&&\mymul{b_{3}}&\myplus& 1 & \\
     \cline{9-10}
     &&&&\mymul{a_{2}}&\myplus&&& a_{4} & \\
     \cline{7-10}
     &&&&&&\mymul{a_{3}}&\myplus& b_{4} & \\
     \cline{9-10}
     &&&&&&&& a_{4} & \\
\end{array}
\intertext{and}
\begin{array}{l*3{|l>{$}p{1.5em}<{$}}|lll}
     \mymul{x_{0}=b_{0}}&\myplus&\multicolumn{3}{l}{$1$} \\
     \cline{3-10}
     &&&&\mymul{b_{2}}&\myplus& 1 && \\
     \cline{7-10}
     &&&&&&\mymul{a_{3}}&\myplus& b_{4} & +  \\
     \cline{9-10}
     &&\mymul{a_{1}}&\myplus&&&&& a_{4} &+ \\
     \cline{5-10}
     &&&&&&\mymul{b_{3}}&\myplus& 1  \\
     \cline{9-10}
     &&&&\mymul{a_{2}}&\myplus&&& a_{4} & + \\
     \cline{7-10}
     &&&&&&\mymul{a_{3}}&\myplus& b_{4}  \\
     \cline{9-10}
     &&&&&&&& a_{4}  \\
\end{array}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you and that looks very good.

Comment: @user91822 You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!

Comment: TBH, I had to make some slight changes. For instance (on the 2nd or last equation), on both the "+[(b_{4}+)/(a_{4}+)]" and the "+[1/(a_{4}+)]" to move the right "+" signs closer to the fractions. Doing so will leave the last item "[+(b_{4}/a_{4})]" with their fraction bar longer extends out and I don't know how to fix it. But, that is OK. So far, so good.

Comment: @user91822 You could ask another question, I'll answer if no one else does it before me, do not hesitate to ask again!